# AmazonAPI get next page from bottlenose search

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottlenose

When doing a keyword search, how do I invoke the next page to receive the next 10 results?

```
amazon = bottlenose.Amazon(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG,Parser=lambda text: BeautifulSoup(text, 'xml'))
response = amazon.ItemSearch(Keywords=searchTerm, SearchIndex="All")
```

response contains first 10 results. I can't figure out how to get the next 10 and so on...

Comment: did you find anything on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you managed to get this sorted but if you add ItemPage="#" it will return that page number of results.

```
response = amazon.ItemSearch(Keywords=searchTerm, SearchIndex="All", ItemPage="2")
```

I have recently just found this out myself. I think it has to do with the arguments being encoded into the URL as parameters so some of them off the API reference sheet work but maybe not all.